# Would Firebase work for a location-based app?

Tags: firebase, geofire

I saw that Firebase has a library for geolocation queries called Geofire, however in a question here on StackOverflow it's said that it doesn't allow extra conditions.

I need to search for places around a location with some attributes (like payments on credit card, valet parking, etc.). How can I overcome this limitation?

Will I have to mix Firebase for features like user authentication and communication with a backend made with ASP.Net Web API for instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Firebase using geofire. Geofire would query the locations in the area and return them. Then you could filter the results according to your criteria.

Comment: Actually this information I already have in my question, I know Geofire, but as I've mentioned, it doesn't support multiple criteria.